# Thevenin Resistance and Voltage

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-divider, thevenin

[image]

So I've confirmed the Thevenin voltage ( between A and B ) to be .5V and a the VLoad as .3633V. I'm now supposed to verify that RLoad is 4k by redrawing the circuit as its Thevenin equivalent and using voltage division.

My Thevenin resistance was 1.125k. I shorted V1 and opened I1, then combined R2 + R6 in series as well as R3 + R5 in series. Then I combined the three remaining resistors in parallel.

When I use voltage division, I get VLoad = .3912V, which is of course greater than .3633. Is there something wrong with my process or calculations that anyone can see?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the Thevenin resistance, don't combine R3 and R5 in series.  The junction of R3 and R5 is one of your terminals. Do this: R2 and R6 in series. The result in parallel with R4. That result in series with R3. Finally that result in parallel with R5.